# How to built expandable Lists in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, expand

[image]

How to achieve this when an icon in app bar is clicked in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the three dots then PopupMenuButton is the way to go:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chat'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 1,
                child: Text("Do something..."),
              ),
            ],
            onSelected: (value) async => {
              _doSomething(),
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: something here...
    );
```